# Matplot is showing a blank rectangle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am stuck and I cannot find the answer to this problem anywhere.

A line graph is not getting displayed only a blank rectangle canvas

Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
new_list=[]
for i in range(50):
    a=random.randint(1,100)
    new_list.append(a)

new_list_y=[]
for i in range(50):
    b=random.randint(1,100)
    new_list_y.append(b)

arr_x=np.array(new_list)
arr_y=np.array(new_list_y)
plt.plot(x=arr_x,y=arr_y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: suppose I do this a= plt.plot(x=arr_x,y=arr_y) and type(a) will this be an axis object? It should not be as I am creating the plot "a" on the axis object? or it will be an axis object itself

Comment: incidentally `import numpy as np`, `arr_x = np.random.randint(1,100,50)` would be a lot cleaner

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of the x and y in your plt.plot statement it works fine:

```
new_list=[]
for i in range(50):
    a=random.randint(1,100)
    new_list.append(a)

new_list_y=[]
for i in range(50):
    b=random.randint(1,100)
    new_list_y.append(b)

arr_x=np.array(new_list)
arr_y=np.array(new_list_y)
plt.plot(arr_x,arr_y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for your help but ideally it should have worked with the x and y. Do you know why it failed ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285820/matplotlib-does-not-plot-when-named-arguments-are-passed It is because plt.plot doesn't accept any named arguments, calling `x=[]` makes your x value a `kwarg` not an `arg`

Comment: the plot function doesn't internally handle named params x and y 
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Comment: @MasonCaiby I got it, thank you. I have one more question suppose i do something like this a=plt.plot(arr_x,arr_y). What will be the type of this object "a" will this be an axis object. It should not be as I am creating the plot "a" on the axis object? or it will be an axis object itself –

Comment: @ChyanitSingh If I understand your question correctly... you can just do this: `a = plt.plot(arr_x,arr_y)
print(type(a))` and see that a is `<class 'list'>`. Then if you `print(a)` you'll get `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x20d130ca3c8>]` so a list of 1 plt object.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to give named params `x` and `y`
Just pass the arguments directly like

```
plt.plot(arr_x,arr_y)
```